# Django calls other template instead of default

Tags: python, html, django

I've made my own login.html name to login1.html instead of deleting it,
and now I'm using Django-registration and Django-registration-views from Github,
but still, Django calls registration/login1.html.
how can I restore it to call the login.html ??

as we can change the default path of templates, is there any way to change default name of a template from login1.html to login.html ?

Comment: You would usually do template lookup in the view function. It's often hard coded there.

Comment: With class based views, template names are also sometimes configured in the url router by using something like this `RegistrationView.as_view(template_name='login1.html')`.

Comment: I don't call login1.html anywhere in my code @HåkenLid

Comment: Then Django will not look for that template name. Your bug is caused by something else. If you need help debugging, provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

it was hard coded at python3.5/site-packages/registration/auth_urls.py

thanks to @HåkenLid